# SOLR loose match with spaces

Tags: solr

I have the below schema in solr and I am doing text match Below are the Fields and copyfield.

```
 <!-- A text type with min processing  -->
    <fieldType name="text_min" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!--
     NGram processing for substrings 
    -->
    <fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>



<field name="namedescription" type="text_min" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="namedescription_ngram" type="text_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" />

<field name="namedescr" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

 <copyField source="namedescription" dest="namedescr"/>
 <copyField source="namedescription_ngram" dest="namedescr"/>
```

My Input: Lorem Ipsum stuff
Search: Lorem Ipsum stuff (matches)
         Lorem Ipsum (Matches)
         Lorem or Ipsum or Stuf (matches)
 ***** ===>     Lorem Ips (doesnt match. ) or ipsum stu (doesnt match. )

What do i have to add as the analyzer shows a match with the namedescription field. Am I missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

First - You are copying the `namedescription` and the `namedescription_ngram` into the `namedescr` field.

Second - You are querying `namedescr`. The `copyField` does the following - "The original text is sent from the "source" field to the "dest" field, before any configured analyzers for the originating or destination field are invoked." according to [this site](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields)

If you query `Lorem Ips` and `ipsum stu` on the fields `namedescription` and `namedescription_ngram`, it will work but not on `namedescr`.

Since `namedescr` does not generate `N-Grams` there will be no results.

Comment: so should I use the different fields and boost them accordingly?

Comment: Also my text_min has an ngram Factory,

Comment: First try to query on namedescription and namedescription_ngram. Then check whether for Lorem Ips the docs are coming or not.